# Dictionary where values can be either a list or a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I am trying to plot the result of truck routing optimization using networkx library. First I must prepare the data and I am stuck.

Here is small example of the initial data:

```
Vehicle       Route  
0       V0   [0,3](V0) 
1       V0   [3,0](V0)  
2       V1   [0,3](V1) 
3       V1   [0,8](V1) 
4       V1   [2,0](V1) 
5       V1   [3,2](V1) 
6       V1   [8,0](V1)
```

There are two trucks: V0 and V1. The route for V0 is: 0 to 3 to 0. But V1 has TWO routes: 0 to 8 to 0 AND 0 to 3 to 2 to 0.

Every tour must start and end at node 0.

I must solve two issues:

1. For each truck (V0, V1) I must find all the tours within a given list that starts and end with zero
2. The flow of tours can not have breaks: the end of each sub-tour [0,8] must be the beginning of the next one [8,0]

the final result must look:

```
{'V0': [0,3,0], 'V1': [[0,3,2,0], [0,8,0]]}
```

I have a code but it does not produce what I want:

```
tours = {'V0': ['0,3', '3,0'], 'V1': ['0,3', '0,8', '2,0', '3,2', '8,0']}


def convert_to_list(s):
    return list(map(int, s.split(',')))

# Function to process each value in the 'tours' dictionary
def process_value(value):
    result = []
    current_list = []

    for pair in value:
        pair_list = convert_to_list(pair)

        if not current_list or pair_list[0] == 0:
            current_list.extend(pair_list)
        elif pair_list[1] == 0:
            current_list.append(pair_list[0])
            current_list.append(0)
            result.append(current_list)
            current_list = [0]
        else:
            current_list.append(pair_list[0])

    if current_list:
        current_list.append(0)
        result.append(current_list)

    return result

# Create the 'tours1' dictionary using the processing functions
tours1 = {key: process_value(value) for key, value in tours.items()}

# Print the result
print(tours1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'V0': [[0, 3, 3, 0], [0, 0]], 'V1': [[0, 3, 0, 8, 2, 0], [0, 3, 8, 0], [0, 0]]}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Avoid special cases in your data. Just make it always a list of lists, then you don't have to treat the single-route case specially.

Comment: Data is ensured to be valid?

Comment: It is the output from the optimizer (Gurobi). It is not my decision. I eliminated the sub-tours (going through the node more than once). Good point. Maybe in such a case, it is not solvable...

Comment: I mean is the route ensured to be from 0 to 0 without any breaks or should you add a validator?

Comment: 100% of every tour must start and end at Node 0. All other tours are compliant with this rule. There must be a code that builds the tour or tours from the list..This is where I am stuck. One potential: sort Route column values to build tours for each truck there.

Comment: Is there always only one road per truck that goes through each point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want the [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) of each vehicle :

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from itertools import chain, groupby

NODE = 0

d = {}

for vehicle, routes in tours.items():
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_edges_from([[*map(int, x.split(","))] for x in routes])

    s = pd.Series(chain.from_iterable(nx.eulerian_path(G, source=NODE)))
       
    d[vehicle] = (s.groupby((s.eq(NODE) & s.iloc[1:-1].duplicated()).cumsum())
                    .agg(lambda x: [k for k, _ in groupby(x)]).tolist())
```

Output :

```
print(d) # {'V0': [[0, 3, 0]], 'V1': [[0, 3, 2, 0], [0, 8, 0]]}
```

Tours of both vehicles :

[image]

**Update** (*requested in the comments*) :

To conditionally color the nodes, you can use :

```
colors = {
    k: "black" if k == 0
    else "green" if 1 <= k <= 4
    else "red" for k in range(10)
}

# to put inside the outer loop
for node in G.nodes:
    G.nodes[node]["style"] = "filled"
    G.nodes[node]["fillcolor"] = colors[node]
    if node == 0:
        G.nodes[node]["fontcolor"] = "white"
```

Comment: Timeless - How would you display the graphics?

Comment: At first, I thought of displaying all truck routes on one graph, but it looks very busy. Your idea of one vehicle tour(s) per graph is much better!

Comment: AFK but for the visualizations, I used pygraphviz. You can add these lines right after making `G` inside the loop : `from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph; A = to_agraph(G); A.layout("dot")`. Then (*always inside the loop*), you can `display(A)` if you're using Jupyter. Or `A.draw(f"{vehicle}.png")` to save an image for each graph/vehicle.

Comment: Thanks! I would guess from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph is NOT inside the loop. Also: A = to_agraph(G); A.layout("dot"); display(A) INSIDE the loop AFTER d[vehicle] = (s.groupby((s.eq(NODE) & s.iloc[1:-1].duplicated()).cumsum())
                    .agg(lambda x: [k for k, _ in groupby(x)]).tolist()) Correct?

Comment: Timeless - works as a dream!! I will mark your answer as the best, but the other two answers are great as well. Great job, EVERYONE! Thank YOU!

Comment: a question. I want to color nodes in different colors. 1 through 4 - green, 5 through 10 - red. 0 - black. Using your code, I started with: colors = ['black' if node == 0 else 'green' if node in S else 'red' for node in G]; S=[1,2,3,4]. But nx.draw(G, pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G), \
    node_size=1000, node_color=colors, linewidths=0.25, , with_labels=True) did not really work. Any hints?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to color the nodes (*using graphviz/dot*). PS : We're kind of getting off track from the main question ;)

Comment: I fixed the Key error. 1. Replaced the dictionary of colors with a list. 2:     for node, color in zip(G.nodes, colors):
        G.nodes[node]["style"] = "filled"
        G.nodes[node]["fillcolor"] = color

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution in O(N^2) where N is the number of nodes, if no point can be reached twice.

```py
tours = {'V0': ['0,3', '3,0'], 'V1': ['0,3', '0,8', '2,0', '3,2', '8,0']}


def process(value):
    result = []  # the final result

    nodes = {}  # a dictionary in the form of start_node: end_node
    starts = []  # a list of pairs (start, end) where start is 0

    for val in value:  # goes through each step
        a, b = val.split(",")  # get start and end
        nodes[a] = b  # add the node to nodes
        if a == "0":  # if the step is a start, add it to starts
            starts.append((a, b))

    for a, b in starts:  # go through each starts
        inter = [a, b]  # list representing one route
        while b != "0":  # as long as we didn't return to 0, continue
            b = nodes[b]  # get the next node
            inter.append(b)  # add it to the route
        result.append(inter)

    return result


def convert():
    """
    Goes through each truck and process it's routes.
    """
    result = {}
    for k, v in tours.items():
        result[k] = process(v)
    return result


print(convert())
```

This gave the result:

`{'V0': [['0', '3', '0']], 'V1': [['0', '3', '2', '0'], ['0', '8', '0']]}`

If you want the second list to be of dimension 1, you can just add an if check in the process method like so:

```py
def process(value):
    result = []  # the final result

    nodes = {}  # a dictionary in the form of start_node: end_node
    starts = []  # a list of pairs (start, end) where start is 0

    for val in value:  # goes through each step
        a, b = val.split(",")  # get start and end
        nodes[a] = b  # add the node to nodes
        if a == "0":  # if the step is a start, add it to starts
            starts.append((a, b))

    for a, b in starts:  # go through each starts
        inter = [a, b]  # list representing one route
        while b != "0":  # as long as we didn't return to 0, continue
            b = nodes[b]  # get the next node
            inter.append(b)  # add it to the route
        result.append(inter)

    if len(result) == 1:
        return result[0]
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Main idea is to organize the data into a tree and then do a depth-first-search to retrieve the valid routes.

Organize data into tree:

```
tours = {'V0': ['0,3', '3,0'], 'V1': ['0,3', '0,8', '2,0', '3,2', '8,0']}

tours2 = {}

for vehicle, routes in tours.items():
    route_tree = {}
    for route in routes:
        frm,to = route.split(',')
        frm = int(frm)
        to = int(to)
        
        if frm in route_tree:
            route_tree[frm].append(to)
        else:
            route_tree[frm] = [to]
    tours2[vehicle] = route_tree
```

tours2:

```
{'V0': {0: [3], 3: [0]}, 'V1': {0: [3, 8], 2: [0], 3: [2], 8: [0]}}
```

DFS for valid routes:

```
routes = {}

for vehicle in tours2:
    running_routes = [[0]]
    completed_routes = []

    while running_routes:
        running_route = running_routes.pop()
        
        if running_route[-1] == 0 and len(running_route) > 1:
            completed_routes.append(running_route)
        else:
            for nxt_node in tours2[vehicle][running_route[-1]]:
                running_routes.append(running_route + [nxt_node])

    routes[vehicle] = completed_routes
```

routes:

```
{'V0': [[0, 3, 0]], 'V1': [[0, 8, 0], [0, 3, 2, 0]]}
```